# dell t710 windows stop error

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell, stoperror

w2k3 OS shuts down unexpected. Windows suggests check disks for errors. any tools? my disks are seagate 1TB 7.2 RPM nearline SAS.

Comment: Troubleshooting a stop error generally requires the stop code.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the tool](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd&releaseid=R247886&SystemID=PWE_R710&servicetag=&os=WNET&osl=en&deviceid=196&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=4&catid=13&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=13&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=362324) pro support has had me use in the past for hard disk issues.